swap matched columns
I have an awk issue need your help,I just need to grep on the second column and if matched,swap the second column with the first column.
172.21.154.40 172.21.254.25
172.21.250.94 172.21.154.37
172.21.250.93 172.21.254.24

My awk script:
awk '$2 == "172.21.154.37"' $outputfile 

then swap 172.21.250.94 with 172.21.154.37
Could anyone help?Thanks.

The answers to your previous question "Identify lines with duplicate column 1 entries and swap columns if found" already do 90% of what you're asking for here (swap the values of 2 fields) and the script in your question does the remaining 10% (compare the 2nd column to a value). It's important to think about and learn from the answers you get, not just keep asking slightly different variations of the same questions.

In awk this can be done on this way:
awk '$2 == "172.21.154.37" {a=$1;$1=$2;$2=a}1' input.file


One idea where we redefine $0 if we find a match:
$ awk '$2 == "172.21.154.37" { $0 = $2 OFS $1 } 1' file.dat
172.21.154.40 172.21.254.25
172.21.154.37 172.21.250.94
172.21.250.93 172.21.254.24

NOTES:

the standalone 1 is awk's equivalent to 'true' and basically says to print the current line (which in this case means we print all lines)
the OFS default is a space; if the input delimiter is something other than a space (eg, 3 spaces) and you wish to retain the input spacing then we could add some more code but at this point the single space appears to be sufficient to match your sample input


Let's KISS!
awk '$2 == "172.21.154.37"{print $2, $1; next} 1' file

This is the same as:
awk '$2 == "172.21.154.37"{print $2, $1; next} {print}' file

In pseudo code:
for each lines:
    if $2 is_equal to "172.21.154.37"
    then print $2 $1
    else print $0


Using Miller:
$ mlr --nidx put  '$2 == "172.21.154.37"{@tmp=$1; $1=$2;$2=@tmp}' 


Using sed:
$ sed -E 's/([^ ]*) (172.21.154.37)/\2 \1/'

